# Sql Server WHERE IN with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, where-clause

How can we specify range of values from CASE inside WHERE clause?
This query of mine fails

```
declare @ProductType int

select * from Products 
where ProductLine in 
(
    case @ProductType
        when 1 then ('TVs')
        when 2 then ('Handsets', 'Mobiles') --fails here
        else ('Books')
    end
)
```

This wouldn't work either:

```
declare @ProductType int

select * from Products 
where (case @ProductType 
             when 1 then (ProductLine = 'TVs')
             when 2 then (ProductLine in  ('Handsets', 'Mobiles'))
             else (ProductLine = 'Books')
       end)
```

Comment: Is `Products` a base table or a view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do that - you need to split it to several checks:

```
WHERE (ProductLine = 'TVs' AND @ProductType = 1)
   OR (ProductLine IN ('Handsets', 'Mobiles') AND @ProductType = 2)
   OR (ProductLine = 'Books' AND @ProductType NOT IN (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @ProductType int

select * from Products 
where (case @ProductType 
             when 1 then ProductLine in ('TVs') 
             when 2 then ProductLine in  ('Handsets', 'Mobiles') 
             else ProductLine in ('Books') end)
```

Comment: Very nice, how couldn't I get it myself ;-) +1

Comment: Yes, it's simple as I found that on the Internet while ago

Comment: It doesn't work. Says `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'`

Comment: I have tried the query and it works fine. You can change the query from `when 1 then ProductLine in ('TVs')` to `when 1 then ProductLine = 'TVs'` and see if it works

Comment: It now says `Incorrect syntax near '='`. Tried putting `ProductLine = 'TVs'` in `()`, still doesn't work.

Comment: Then can you update your answer with the new code so I can have a look

Comment: @Nick: Updated my question with your solution.

Comment: @ReddySR I don't have any idea now, because your query does work fine for me. You can change it back to `select * from Products where ProductLine = 'TVs'` then modify it step by step, you may find some ideas

Comment: @Nick What database do you use? This does not work in Sql Server because there is not boolean datatype.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović it works fine in MSSQL. Also this is not a boolean, it just bases on the ProductType value and get different where clause

Comment: @Nick It doesn't work in 2005, 2008 and 2012. Please check this [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f927b/1) for 2012 and 2008 R2 versions (change DB from the menu next to logo).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović then I don't know why, because my query is running fine without any problem in both MSSQL and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take with this one. My first option would be to use a sub-query or common table expression to invert the logic and return the product type, and then match on product type. The second would be to use 'sp_executesql'.

First option:

```
declare @ProductType int

WITH cte (Product_key, ProductType) AS (
    SELECT Product_key, CASE WHEN ProductLine IN ('TVs') THEN 1
        WHEN ProductLine IN ('Handsets', 'Mobiles') THEN 2  
        ELSE 3 END FROM Products
)
select p.* from Products p, cte 
where p.product_key = cte.product_key AND cte.ProductType = @ProductType
```

Second option:

```
declare @ProductType int, @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'select * from Products 
    where ProductLine in (' +
        case @ProductType
            when 1 then '''TVs'''
            when 2 then '''Handsets'', ''Mobiles'''
            else '''Books'''
        end + ')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: +1 for your second option. But zerkms's solution sets best for my situation. Thanks for your idea though.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a value.  `IN` is a clause that may be part of a query.  And SQL Server only grudgingly supports a boolean data type.

You can combine them thusly:

```
declare @ProductType int = 1
declare @Products as Table ( ProductLine VarChar(16) )
insert into @Products ( ProductLine ) values ( 'TVs' ), ( 'Books' )
select *
  from @Products  
  where
    case @ProductType 
      when 1 then ( select 1 where ProductLine in ('TVs') )
      when 2 then ( select 1 where ProductLine in ('Handsets', 'Mobiles') )
      else ( select 1 where ProductLine in ('Books') )
      end is not NULL
```