# SQL server. i want to select multiple values in where clause using case

Tags: sql-server

The column status_ of table 2 contain multiple status (e.g 0,1,2,3,4,5,6).

How can I return values from table 2 on the basis of condition?

```sql
declare @role_id int = null,
        @user_id int = 197
    select @role_id=role from table1
    
select * from table2
    where 
    status_= case when @role_id in (12,13,14) then (0,1)
                  when @role_id in (15,16,17) then (2,3,4)
                  else (5,6)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sql Server WHERE IN with CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508684/sql-server-where-in-with-case)

Comment: How can a single column have multiple items in it? Is it really just a comma-separated list of type `varchar`? If so then you have a design issue